# Raspberry Pi Camera: Picamera2: Cannot configure camera in the middle of a stream

Tags: python, pi-3b+, picamera

I'm making a remote config PiCamera for astrophotography, using the official Camera Module 3. When the user configures the camera, my application sends a request in JSON format over an HTTP socket. The problem is, when the user sets a config value, the picamera has to be stopped, configured and restarted again. This results in this error:

```
[0:07:28.333293358] [1771]  INFO Camera camera_manager.cpp:299 libcamera v0.0.4+22-923f5d70
[0:07:28.492082023] [1794]  INFO RPI raspberrypi.cpp:1476 Registered camera /base/soc/i2c0mux/i2c@1/imx708@1a to Unicam device /dev/media1 and ISP device /dev/media0
[0:07:28.617104687] [1771]  INFO Camera camera.cpp:1028 configuring streams: (0) 4608x2592-XBGR8888
[0:07:28.617987807] [1794]  INFO RPI raspberrypi.cpp:851 Sensor: /base/soc/i2c0mux/i2c@1/imx708@1a - Selected sensor format: 4608x2592-SBGGR10_1X10 - Selected unicam format: 4608x2592-pBAA
[0:07:29.166559071] [1794] ERROR V4L2 v4l2_videodevice.cpp:1248 /dev/video14[24:cap]: Not enough buffers provided by V4L2VideoDevice
Error: Failed to allocate buffers.. Killing server...
```

The part of my code that produced this error:

```
elif data["command"] == "set":
    _config[data["key"]] = data["value"]
    picam2.stop_recording()
    # Reset the camera to apply the new settings
    picam2.close()
    picam2 = Picamera2()
    time.sleep(0.1)
    picam2.configure(picam2.create_video_configuration({"size": picam2.sensor_resolution}, controls=_config))
    picam2.start_recording(JpegEncoder(), FileOutput(output))
    _log("Set config value successfully!")
```

Can anyone tell me why this is happening? How can I fix this? I turned up my GPU memory to 512, but it still doesn't work.